# Firing javascript event in woocommerce causing breakdown of the script

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

my problem is that when i upload my code into wordpress, it doing fine on his own, taking values from json placed in form, and changing select fields according to clicked image. But when i try to fire any event, even change on select to change price of product, it causing massive lag/break of the script and sometimes error that i exceeded stack size.

Here is my site:
http://codevly.com/did/produkt/koszulka-kopia-3/

Click on image to see effect, sometimes even it not working at all and selects are empty

Here is my script:

```
 function mytheme_enqueue_typekit() {  if ( is_product()) {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'script-change', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/script-change.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
     wp_add_inline_script( 'script-change', 'jQuery.noConflict();
                (function( $ ) {

                $(document).ready(function(){

                var click = false;
                var dane = $(".variations_form.cart").attr("data-product_variations");
                dane = JSON.parse(dane);
                    $(".product-type-variable > .woocommerce-product-gallery > ol.flex-control-nav > li > img").click(function(e){
                            magic( $(this), dane, function(){
                                });


                    });


                $(".product-type-variable > .woocommerce-product-gallery > ol").mouseup(function(e){

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $(".summary select").trigger("change").trigger("select.fs");
                     }, 1000);

                });

                function magic(object, dane, callback){
                    //ustalanie zmiennych
                    var warianty = new Array();
                    $("table.variations").find("select").each( function(index, val){
                        warianty.push($(this).attr("id"));
                    });

                    //------------
                    for(var val in dane){
                        val = dane[val];
                        //console.log(val);
                        var x = val["image"]["gallery_thumbnail_src"];
                        var full = x.substring(x.lastIndexOf("/"));
                        var href = object.attr("src");
                        href = href.substring(href.lastIndexOf("/"));

                        if(full === href){

                            for(var i=0; i < warianty.length; i++){
                                val2 = warianty[i];
                                //$("select#"+val2).val(val["attributes"]["attribute_"+val2]).change();
                                //console.log(val2);
                                $("form.variations_form > table.variations > tbody > tr > td.value > select#"+val2).val(val["attributes"]["attribute_"+val2]);
                            }

                        }
                        callback();
                    }

                }


  });
})(jQuery);' );
  }
}
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_enqueue_typekit' );
```

Comment: what do you see if you console.log(dane)? i see an error saying 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <', which to me indicates JSON.parse is being passed html instead of a json object.

Comment: Now it should parse json properly